# edismax query - how to achieve db2 like search in solr

Tags: solr, db2

We are using edismax for searching with multiple keywords. The results are random if we are giving wild card search keywords.

Below is the query we are pulling from datastax:

```
select * from test.searchtest where solr_query = '{"q":"{!edismax qf=first_name}(Beacon Watt)"}' limit 50;
```

results:

```
Beacon Watt
Test Beacon Watt
Watt
```

I am expecting something like db2 like search functionality. eg: it should return the results like

```
Beacon Watt
Beacon Watter
Beacon Wattff
etc.
```

Is there any way to achieve this in solr.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Does edismax support the ~ for edit distance?

Comment: not sure, but does it impact?